# Select record based on date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have been stuck with this for a while now, but it is probably something simple.

What I am trying to do is to select a value from one table based on date from another.

For example I have a table where I've got rates and a date when they start:

```
Rate ID    Worker_ID    Rate    Rate_Date 
 1            3         2.50    01-06-2017
 2            4         3.00    01-06-2017
 3            3         4.50    23-08-2017
```

Then I have a table with information when the work was carried out:

```
LabourID    Worker_ID    Hours   Date
1             3          2.00    02-06-2017
2             4          3.50    03-06-2017
3             3          1.00    23-08-2017
```

Worker 3 had a change in work rate on 23/08. I would like the records before that date to use rate up to that date and records after that date to use rate including and after that date. If there is additional rate, eg in 2 weeks, I would like for that rate to be used in the records after that Rate_date, but previous records to use relevent date.

Comment: Sorry my bad, MS SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume cross apply is available in your RDBMS...

This essentially selects all records from WorkInfo
and then only the most recent rate record less than or equal to the work date  for that worker.

```
SELECT *
FROM WorkInfo WI
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Top 1  R.*
             FROM Rate R 
             WHERE WI.Worker_ID = R.Worker_ID 
               and R.Rate_date <= WI.Date
             ORDER BY Rate_date Desc)
```

Cross apply essentially executes the query for every record in WI using correlation between the tables.  It is generally extremely efficient for queries such as these.